# how can i delete reserved dedupe rules in civicrm

Tags: dedupe-rules

i'am using civicrm and i want to delete some dedupe rules but the problem i dont see the buttom delete.
Can you help me please ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can't from the backoffice, you need to edit the rule in the table `civicrm_dedupe_rule_group` and set `is_reserved` to `0`